# Expressions are almost identic but one of them is not working

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression

`Expressions` are not really identic, but should be. They differ in one slight details. I am quite new to `Expressions`, but I think this could be confusing even for quite experienced player. I refactored the code which processes some data to make `Expression` used as parameter for `IQueryable.Where()`. It is functionally equivalent as far as I can see.

I have here former code, which worked well, and generates perfectly functional Expression:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> StringPropertyContains<T>(string propertyName, string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyName));
    }

    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    MemberExpression member = null;
    if (propertyName.Contains('/'))
    {
        var splittedPropertyName = propertyName.Split('/');

        var propertyInfo = this.GetPropertyInfo(typeof(T), splittedPropertyName.First());
        member = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, propertyInfo);

        for (int i = 1; i < splittedPropertyName.Length; i++)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsInterface)
            {
                //specifically for IActorWithExtraDetails -> reason to refactor
                if (typeof(IActor).IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType) && typeof(IActor).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(pi => pi.Name.Equals(splittedPropertyName[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) != null)
                {
                    propertyInfo = this.GetPropertyInfo(typeof(IActor), splittedPropertyName[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    propertyInfo = this.GetPropertyInfo(propertyInfo.PropertyType, splittedPropertyName[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                propertyInfo = this.GetPropertyInfo(propertyInfo.PropertyType, splittedPropertyName[i]);
            }

        }

        member = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(member, propertyInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        var propertyInfo = this.GetPropertyInfo(typeof(T), propertyName);

        member = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, propertyInfo);
    }

    var constant = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));
    var methodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    var body = Expression.Call(member, methodInfo, constant);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
}
```

This is how it looks in `DebugView` property of the `IQueryable`:

```
.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[AccessManagement.Model.Application,System.Boolean]>(AccessManagement.Model.Application $var1)
{
    .Call ($var1.Name).Contains("hive")
}
```

Here is new, refactored code moved to own method:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> StringPropertyContains<T>(string propertyName, string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyName));
    }

    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    MemberExpression member = this.GetMemberExpression(typeof(T), propertyName.Trim('/').Split('/'));

    var constant = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));
    var methodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    var body = Expression.Call(member, methodInfo, constant);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
}

    private MemberExpression GetMemberExpression(Type baseType, string[] path)
    {
        MemberExpression result = null;
        Type type = baseType;
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = null;

        foreach (string segment in path)
        {
            //if type is interface, just spray and pray
            if (type.IsInterface)
            {
                propertyInfo = this.GetDescendantProperties(type)
                    .FirstOrDefault(pi => pi.Name.Equals(segment, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            }
            else
            {
                propertyInfo = this.GetPropertyInfo(type, segment);
            }

            if (propertyInfo == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyInfo));
            }

            result =
                result == null ?
                    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Parameter(baseType), propertyInfo) :
                    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(result, propertyInfo);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This is how expression from refactored method looks like in `DebugView`:

```
.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[AccessManagement.Model.Application,System.Boolean]>(AccessManagement.Model.Application $var1)
{
    .Call ($var2.Name).Contains("hive")
}
```

There is only one difference. As you can see, there is `$var2` in second case, not `$var1`. This variable doesn't exist in whole expression tree. I have no idea why, but I'd bet that is the issue, because everything else remains same. Only other difference is that within second case `Expression` processing is something cachced in `member.RuntimeMethodInfo.base.m_cachedData` (debug view path).

Comment: The first code snippet makes use of the `param` expression, while the second one ignores it.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski sorry! terrible mistake, I forgot to add refactored expression processing, edited -- however `param` is used in the last line of the first method of the second snippet

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I said :) See this code `Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Parameter(baseType), propertyInfo)`, replace `Expression.Parameter(baseType)` with a reference to `param`, the same one that you pass to `Expression.Lambda`. You're creating a second unrelated parameter here, that's where `$var2` comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code snippet, you're declaring a parameter:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
```

This is used as the lambda parameter, and is used in the code here:

```
 Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, propertyInfo);
```

(this is called twice actually). So the code makes use of the parameter passed to the lambda.

---

In your second code snippet, you're still using `param` as the parameter to the lambda, but then you don't use it anywhere in the lambda body.

You're calling this instead:

```
Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Parameter(baseType), propertyInfo)
```

That `Expression.Parameter(baseType)` creates a second and *unrelated* variable, which never gets an actual value assigned to it. You should have used the `param` reference here.

That's where `$var2` comes from. `$var1` is the `param` reference.

Consider using the `Expression.Parameter(Type, string)` overload next time, which lets you name your parameters for debugging purposes. It'll be easier to reason about.